# Php #home page does not redirect

Tags: php, jquery, html

**I am working on an app. but Have a problem with the login system. I want to redirect users into (http://localhost/Media/Index.php#Home) if they logged in correctly. But it does not seem to work as of now. When I type the login info it just reload and nothing happens. Please help!**

```
<?php include ("inc/scripts/mysql_connect.inc.php"); ?>
<?php
session_start(); //Start session
//Check if user is logged in or not
if (isset($_SESSION['user_login'])) {
$user = $_SESSION["user_login"];
 }
else {
$user = ""; //Do nothing
//echo"Sorry but your are not logged in!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"; 
}
?>
<?php
//Login Script
//user Login code
//Check user info when user inputs login information
if (isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['password_login']) )
{
//filters input info
$user_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9)]#i','', $_POST['user_login']);//filters everything but numbers and letters
$password_login = preg_replace('#[^A-Za-z0-9)]#i','', $_POST['password_login']);//filters everything but numbers and letters
$password_login_md5 = md5($password_login); // encrypt password input because password in database is already encrypted in md5
//use Binary for case sensitive option
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY username= BINARY'$user_login' AND password='$password_login_md5' AND closed='no' LIMIT 1"); //query
//check for existence if user exists
$userCount = mysqli_num_rows($sql); //Count the number of rows returned
//if username exists start session
if($userCount==1)
{
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) //fecthing the row to display information
{
$id = $row["id"]; // store user id into variable called $id
}
$_SESSION["id"] = $id;  
$_SESSION['user_login'] = $user_login;
$_SESSION["password_login"] = $password_login;
header("Location: Index.php#Home");//WE WANT USER TO ACCESS THE #HOME PAGE IF THEY ONLY LOGGED IN SUCCESSFULLY
//exit("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0\">");              
}
else{
    //echo"That information is incorrect, Please try again!";
}
exit(); 
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/myThemeEdited.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- The welcome page where users must provide login info in order to be logged in -->
<div data-role="page" id="Welcome">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c">
<h1>Welcome</h1>                    
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
<form  action = "Index.php" method = "POST"><!--provide username and password then submit -->
<input name="user_login" size= "25" placeholder="Username" type="text"/><!-- Enter username / placeholder  username-->
<input data-clear-btn="false" name="password_login" size= "25" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" type="password"/><!-- Enter password /password placeholder-->
<input name="login" value="Login" type="submit" data-theme="c"/><!-- submit button style it later -->
</form>
<div>
<a href="#Home" data-role="button">Sign Up</a><!--Redirect user to sign up page if user not member yet-->
</div>  
</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c"><!-- Footer display/ displays once-->
<h4>(C) 2016</h4><!-- copyright symbols include later-->
</div>
</div><!-- End of the login page-->             


<!-- HOME PAGE AND USER PROFILE PAGE where users can enter and submit texts-->
<div data-role="page" id="Home">
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c"><!-- Jquery settings ref included in the header file-->
<h1>Text</h1>
</div>
<div role="main" class="ui-content">
Enter your text<br>
<!-- Allow users to type and send texts-->
<input name="text-basic" id="text-basic" value="" type="text"/><!-- Enter and send text -->
<a href="" data-role= "button" data-theme="c" onClick="submittext(Q)">Send</a><!-- submit button with onclcick function -->
</div>
</div><!-- End of the Home page-->
</body>
</html><!-- End code-->
```

Comment: Your login form's action property is set to `index.php`, not to `#Home`, so your login is going to just take you back to the page when you click your submit button.

Comment: I only see a `header("Location: Index.php#Home")`, not Media/Index.php#Home

Comment: @SgtAJ but when I type http://localhost/Media/Index.php#Home in the browser I do see my #Home page. This is where I want to bring users only if they logged in.  How can I fix that?

Comment: For one, you shouldn't store the passwords of your users in a session. It's very  bad practice. I recommend you enable [`error_reporting(E_ALL);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)
[`ini_set('display_errors', 1);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php), which would, if I'm guessing, give some "*Headers already sent*" warnings.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I says error loading page when I tried with Header ("Location:Media/Index.php#Home") instead.

Comment: Gotcha.  I was looking at your form's action property, not your header redirect.  However, the redirect is executed before the HTML on the page is loaded, so I don't think it can redirect to an id on the page if that id hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: In order to redirect you need to set the HTTP status code to 302 or equivalent in addition to setting the "Location" header.

Comment: @ Knut Forkalsrud Can I get the content of the Id Home using a document.getElementById whenever the session is active?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment above, I don't think you can use a redirect here, since the redirect is executed before the HTML on the page is loaded, thus the id doesn't exist when you're trying to redirect to it.  You CAN, however, use javascript and `.scrollTop` to do this.

Put this code at the bottom of your page:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['user_login']))
    {
        echo '<script>
                 var x = document.getElementById('Home').scrollTop;
                 document.body.scrollTop = x;
              </script>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: I added the piece of code at the bottom of my html page and when I logged in it does get the id Home. I have a blank page instead with the same http://localhost/Media/Index.php. Can you improve that?

Comment: What?  You said it *does* get the id Home, but the page is blank?  That doesn't make sense.  Just so I'm clear, both your login page and the page you're redirecting users after login is the index.php page?  If they're different pages, you need that code I gave you at the bottom of the page users are sent to after logging in.

Comment: no my bad it does not get the id Home. When I pass in the login info and hit submit I'm still on localhost/Media/Index.php but with a blank page this time.

Comment: So is #Home on the index.php page, or on a different page?  If it's a different page, what page is it?

Comment: #Home is on the index.php page. And I can get to it easily using a tag. But this case is different I want to use a javascript or a php code so that users cannot access #Home unless they are logged in.

Comment: You could simply use PHP to test for your session variable indicating a user logged in and if it's found, output the HTML for #Home.  If a user isn't logged in, don't output that bit of HTML, so it can't be seen at all without a valid login.  Or just redirect to a second page after validating a successful login.